# Why is it taking so long to be ticketed?

Tags: tickets, american-airlines

I paid for a ticket on an American Airlines domestic flight with a credit card yesterday afternoon on aa.com (American's official portal) and it is evening now, so it has been more than 24 hours since I bought the ticket and my status is still "ticket pending".

Why is it taking so long to get "ticketed" status?

Comment: Did you book directly on the American Airline site or a third-party? This makes a huge difference.

Comment: @Itai directly with American, I updated the question.

Comment: Have you checked to see whether the charge went through on your credit card?

Comment: Call the airline.  Voting to close as that's the only valid answer, and it's not really an answer...

Comment: @Doc Just because you don't know the answer doesn't mean someone doesn't know the answer.

Comment: @LemuelGulliver I do know the answer.  And I gave it.

Answer (score 3):

There really isn't a way to find out besides contacting the airline and asking. It's possible there's a payment issue or a delay in coordinating with other airlines (if the itinerary involves segments on other carriers) or just random delays in the reservation system. Without access to the airline's internal systems, we could only speculate.

American [suggests you contact reservations](https://twitter.com/americanair/status/493432725349875712?) by phone. You could also try sending them a direct message on Twitter or Facebook. They can look up the details, see the reasons for the delay, and take steps to get it resolved.